# I need to find the limit of a sequence but not quite sure how to do it.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the sequence $a_n = \frac{6\sqrt{n}}{1+3\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Hint: Can you try with $\frac1{a_n}$ instead? In the other words, can you simplify $\frac{1+3\sqrt n}{6\sqrt n}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{6\sqrt{n}}{1+3\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{6\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{3\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{6}{0+3}=2$$

Comment: thanks so much I forgot I can in a way solve the equation to get the limit

Comment: @GuestAnon u r welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

For large enough $n$, $a_n$ behaves like $6\sqrt{n}/3\sqrt{n} = 2$, so the limit is $2$. Or, if you like, divide top and bottom by $6\sqrt{n}$ to get $$a_n = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{6\sqrt{n} } + \frac{1}{2}} \to \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2.$$